# Probability that 2 numbers selected have same msb.

Tags: probability

### Question

> Consider a $4$ bit binary  representation of decimal number ranging $1$ to $13$.
> What is the probability that 2 numbers selected have same msb?

## My Approach

Converting the decimal number to $4$ bit representation from $1$ to $13$,we have

$0001$,$0010$,$0011$,$0100$,$0101$,$0110$,$0111$
$1000$,$1001$,$1010$,$1011$,$1100$,$1101$
If we select number whose msb is $0$,we have $6$ options and if we select number
whose msb is $1$,we have $5$ options

so reqd probability$=\frac{6 \times 5}{\binom{13}{2}}=\frac{5}{13}$

Is it correct?
Please help

Comment: What is "msb" ? I guess "most significant bit".

Comment: It seems that they meant most significant bit

Comment: @PeterForeman However, in this case, $7$ numbers have msb $0$ and $6$ have msb $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom72$ ways to choose $0$ as the most significant bit for a pair and $\binom62$ ways to choose $1$ as the most significant bit for a pair.

Hence it should be $$\frac{\binom72 + \binom62}{\binom{13}2}$$